# Compare version strings in Inno Setup

Tags: version, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm reading the value of an INF file, now I need to compare it with the installer version, but when I compile I get an error:

> Unknown identifier: CompareVersion

What is wrong?

```pascal
[Code]

function GetKeyValue(const AKeyName, AFileName, ADefault: string): string;
var  
  I: Integer;
  KeyPos: Integer;
  KeyFull: string;
  FileLines: TArrayOfString;
begin
  Result := ADefault;
  if LoadStringsFromFile(AFileName, FileLines) then
  begin
    KeyFull := AKeyName + '=';
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(FileLines) - 1 do
    begin
      FileLines[I] := TrimLeft(FileLines[I]);
      KeyPos := Pos(KeyFull, FileLines[I]);
      if KeyPos > 0 then
      begin
        Result := Copy(FileLines[I], KeyPos + Length(AKeyName) + 1, MaxInt);
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  L2Ver2: TLabel;

procedure DirEditChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  FilePath: string;
begin
  FilePath := AddBackslash(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text) + 'left4dead2\steam.inf';
  L2Ver2.Caption := GetKeyValue('PatchVersion', FilePath, 'N/A');
  if (CompareVersion( L2Ver2.Caption, '{#MyAppOldVersion}') = 0) then
    begin
      ...
    end 
end;
```

I have the error in this line:

```pascal
if (CompareVersion( L2Ver2.Caption, '{#MyAppOldVersion}') = 0) then
```

`{#MyAppOldVersion}` is already defined.

This post is related to my previous question: [Read an INF file during the Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717110/read-an-inf-file-during-the-setup-inno-setup-finished).

If anyone can help, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no `CompareVersion` function in Inno Setup *(there is one since 6.1, see below)*.

You need to define your own.

Something like:

```pascal
function CompareVersion(V1, V2: string): Integer;
var
  P, N1, N2: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  while (Result = 0) and ((V1 <> '') or (V2 <> '')) do
  begin
    P := Pos('.', V1);
    if P > 0 then
    begin
      N1 := StrToInt(Copy(V1, 1, P - 1));
      Delete(V1, 1, P);
    end
      else
    if V1 <> '' then
    begin
      N1 := StrToInt(V1);
      V1 := '';
    end
      else
    begin
      N1 := 0;
    end;
  
    P := Pos('.', V2);
    if P > 0 then
    begin
      N2 := StrToInt(Copy(V2, 1, P - 1));
      Delete(V2, 1, P);
    end
      else
    if V2 <> '' then
    begin
      N2 := StrToInt(V2);
      V2 := '';
    end
      else
    begin
      N2 := 0;
    end;

    if N1 < N2 then Result := -1
      else
    if N1 > N2 then Result := 1;
  end;
end;
```

- Returns `0`, if the versions are equal.
- Returns `-1`, if the `V1` is older than the `V2`.
- Returns `1`, if the `V1` is newer than the `V2`.
- `1.12` is considered newer than `1.1`.
- `1.1` is considered the same as `1.1.0`.
- Throws an exception, when a version is syntactically invalid (only digits and dots are allowed).

---

*Inno Setup 6.1 and newer supports version comparing natively with its [`ComparePackedVersion` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_comparepackedversion).*

*Use [`GetPackedVersion`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getpackedversion) to obtain binary version in the required form. And [`PackVersionComponents`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_packversioncomponents) or [`StrToVersion`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_strtoversion) to calculate the packed version for a specific (hardcoded) version for the comparison.*

---

Unit tests:

```pascal
procedure CompareVersionTest(V1, V2: string; Expected: Integer);
var
  R: Integer;
  M: string;
begin
  M := Format('Comparing [%s] vs. [%s] - expecting %d - ', [V1, V2, Expected]);
  R := CompareVersion(V1, V2);
  if R <> Expected then
  begin
    RaiseException(M + Format('Failed - Got %d', [R]));
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(M + 'Passed');
  end;
end;

procedure CompareVersionTests;
begin
  CompareVersionTest('1', '1', 0);
  CompareVersionTest('1.2', '1.2', 0);
  CompareVersionTest('1.2.3', '1.2.3', 0);
  CompareVersionTest('1', '2', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('1', '3', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('2', '3', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('2', '1', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('3', '1', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('3', '2', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('1', '12', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('12', '2', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('12', '12', 0);
  CompareVersionTest('1.2', '1.3', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.3', '1.2', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.2', '11.2', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('11.2', '1.2', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.1', '1.12', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.11', '1.12', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.12', '1.1', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.12', '1.11', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('1', '1.0', 0);
  CompareVersionTest('1.0', '1', 0);
  CompareVersionTest('1', '1.1', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.1', '1', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.12.123', '1.12.124', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.12.124', '1.12.123', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.12.123', '1.13.1', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.13.1', '1.12.123', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.12.123', '1.13', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.13', '1.12.123', 1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.12', '1.13.1', -1);
  CompareVersionTest('1.13.1', '1.12', 1);
end;
```

If you want to run the unit tests, just call `CompareVersionTests` in [`InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup).

Comment: you have helped me a lot, thank you! it works perfectly

Comment: +1. I moved version number extracting to `function NextIntFromVersion(var S: string): Integer;` and then in `CompareVersion` in while loop I just have `Result := NextIntFromVersion(V1) - NextIntFromVersion(V2);`. It changes return values a little: for `V1` older than `V2` you just get negative number, for `V1` newer than `V2` - positive. Other than that it works the same and is a bit shorter. :)

Comment: If anyone needs it, you can avoid exceptions and assume `0` if you replace each `StrToInt` with `StrToIntDef` (use `0` as the 2nd parameter).

Answer (score 4):

Using **InnoSetup 6.1** or newer, you can use the built-in function [`ComparePackedVersion`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_comparepackedversion). It expects version numbers in binary format (`Int64`), so you first have to convert each version using [`StrToVersion`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_strtoversion) from string to binary format.

The following function encapsulates all of this.

```
function CompareVersion( version1, version2: String ): Integer;
var
    packVersion1, packVersion2: Int64;
begin
    if not StrToVersion( version1, packVersion1 ) then packVersion1 := 0;
    if not StrToVersion( version2, packVersion2 ) then packVersion2 := 0;
    Result := ComparePackedVersion( packVersion1, packVersion2 );
end;
```

- Returns 0, if the versions are equal.
- Returns -1, if `version1` is older than `version2`.
- Returns 1, if `version1` is newer than `version2`.
- If a version string is in incorrect format (`StrToVersion` returns `False`) it is considered to be `0.0.0.0`. No exception will be thrown.
- The function passes the unit test from [Martin Prikryl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37826864/7571258).

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this solution that is a bit shorter by using recursion. I wrote it as a procedure in order to return the result from the recursion correctly. Maybe my parameter usage isn't perfect, but it works.

```pascal
procedure VerStrCompare(S1,S2:String; var pComp:Integer);
var nE1,nE2,nV1,nV2:Integer;

begin
 if (Length(S1)>0) OR (Length(S2)>0) then begin
  nE1:=Pos('.',S1+'.');
  nE2:=Pos('.',S2+'.');
  if nE1>1 then nV1:=StrToInt(Copy(s1,1,(nE1-1))) else nV1:=0;
  if nE2>1 then nV2:=StrToInt(Copy(s2,1,(nE2-1))) else nV2:=0;
  if nV1=nV2 then VerStrCompare(Copy(s1,nE1+1,Length(s1)),Copy(s2,nE2+1,Length(s2)),pComp)
   else if nV1>nV2 then pComp:=1
   else if nV1<nV2 then pComp:=-1;
  end 
  else pComp:=0;
end;
```

> Usage: VerStrCompare(String1,String2,Result)
> where Result=0 if both strings are the same dotted decimal versions.
> Result=1 if String1 is newer (higher version) than String2
> Result=-1 if String1 is older (lower version) than String2