# Overwrite existing data file only when installing a newer version of application with Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup to create an installer. When I run an installer of older version (e.g 1.0.0.2) on a computer that already has application of newer version (e.g. 1.0.0.3) installed I don't want files with the same name to be overwritten.

As I understand from here

> 3. If the existing file is a newer version than the file being installed, or if the existing file has version info but the file being installed does not, the existing file will not be replaced.
>      [Inno Setup help, Files section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/)

running an installer of older version over existing newer version must NOT replace existing file.

I've created two installers. Older version (1) has:

```
AppVersion=1.0.0.2
VersionInfoVersion={#SetupSetting('AppVersion')}
```

and the newer version (2) has:

```
AppVersion=1.0.0.3
VersionInfoVersion={#SetupSetting('AppVersion')}
```

Both installers have the same Files section:

```
[Files]
Source: "D:\installer\test1003\*"; DestDir: "{app}\app"; Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

But when I run (1) having (2) installed file with the same name is replaced (and vice versa but that is logical as I understand)

I decided to create log files for both installers and that is what I got:

> Dest filename: C:\Program Files\dir\app\tryout.txt
>   Time stamp of our file: 2019-01-23 13:02:10.000
>   Dest file exists.
>   Time stamp of existing file: 2019-01-23 13:01:50.000
>   Version of our file: (none)
>   Version of existing file: (none)

These parts are identical except for timestamps.

Any ideas on how to set versions for installed files?

Thanks in advance.

I'm not sure if that's important, but I'm using Unicode version of Inno Setup. Now it supports only one version, but I want to add more later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install a certain file, if installing a newer version of the installer only, you can use the following code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5

[Files]
; Overwrite .exe always
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
; Overwrite .dat file only when installing a newer version
Source: "MyProg.dat"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: IsInstallingNewerVersion
```

```pascal
[Code]

{ Update AppId in the key! }
const
  UninstallKey = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\My Program_is1';
  DisplayVersionValue = 'DisplayVersion';

var
  InstallingNewerVersion: Boolean;

function IsInstallingNewerVersion: Boolean;
begin
  Result := InstallingNewerVersion;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  PrevVersion, CurVersion: string;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, UninstallKey, DisplayVersionValue, PrevVersion) or
     RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, UninstallKey, DisplayVersionValue, PrevVersion) then
  begin
    Log(Format('Previous version %s', [PrevVersion]));
    CurVersion := '{#SetupSetting('AppVersion')}';
    Log(Format('Installing version %s', [CurVersion]));
    InstallingNewerVersion := (CompareVersion(PrevVersion, CurVersion) < 0);
    if InstallingNewerVersion then Log('Installing newer version')
      else Log('Not installing newer version')
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

Get the `CompareVersion` function from [Compare version strings in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37825650/850848).

Comment: I'm told to avoid saying "thanks", but that would be rude, I think.
It works just perfect, thank you very much!:)