# How to remove the file added by previous version of an application in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation, pascalscript

I want to uninstall the previously installed application and its associated files and folders before installing the new one.

I referred this solution [Detect and uninstall old version of application in Inno Setup using its version number stored in registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821439/detect-and-uninstall-old-version-of-application-in-inno-setup-using-its-version) – this is working fine, but not removing files and folders which was created by previously installed version.

Example: User has the old version in `c:\test\my program` and now if he changes the location directly into `c`. Then it should delete the old files and folders which are present in `c:\test`. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your installer to delete additional files, use [`[InstallDelete]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installdeletesection).

---

Obviously better would be if the uninstaller deleted those. So if it is still feasible to fix your uninstaller, use [`[UninstallDelete]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=uninstalldeletesection). Refer to the installation path using the [`{app}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=app).

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\MyProgram.ini"
```