# Can we use the new "Version" functions in Inno Setup 6.1 to make the script simpler?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have several places in my script where I work with version numbers:

- Scenario 1

  ```
  #define AppVerText() \
     GetVersionComponents(SourceDir + '\Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe', \
         Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
     Str(Local[0]) + "." + Str(Local[1]) + "." + Str(Local[2])
  ```
- Scenario 2

  ```pascal
  { Is the installed version at least 14.14 ? }
      Result := (Major < 14) or
          ((Major = 14) and ((Minor < 14) or
          ((Minor = 14) and ((Bld < 26429) or
          ((Bld = 26429) and (Rbld < 3))))));
  if (Result) then
  ```

  The various values were extracted from registry keys.
- Scenario 3

  ```pascal
  { Check Windows Version }
  WindowsVersion := GetWindowsVersion;
  Log(Format('Windows Version: %x', [WindowsVersion]));
  (* Windows must be Win 7 SP1 (6.1.7601), Win 8.1 (6.3.9200) or higher,
      eg: Win 10 (10.0.10240)
      See: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes
      Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6.2 will only work with these operating systems. *)
  if (WindowsVersion <  MakeVersion(6, 1, 7601)) or
       ((WindowsVersion >= MakeVersion(6, 2, 0)) and
        (WindowsVersion < MakeVersion(6, 3, 0))) then
  begin
      MsgBox(SetupMessage(msgWindowsVersionNotSupported), mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
  end;
  ```

  Which calls:

  ```pascal
  function MakeVersion(Major, Minor, Build: Cardinal): Cardinal;
  begin
      Result := (Major shl 24) + (Minor shl 16) + Build;
  end;
  ```

I just wondered if we were able to make use of the new "version" Pascal functions etc. introduced in Inno Setup 6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`ComparePackedVersion` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_comparepackedversion) (together with [`PackVersionComponents`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_packversioncomponents)):

```pascal
Result :=
  (ComparePackedVersion(
    PackVersionComponents(Major, Minor, Bld, Rbld),
    PackVersionComponents(14, 14, 26429, 3)) < 0);
```

It's not much improvement in terms of code length. But it's way less error prone and easier to understand.

I believe it's actually safe to compare the packed versions numbers directly (at least unless your major version is not higher than 2^15). Though `PackVersionComponents` discourages that.

```pascal
Result :=
  (PackVersionComponents(Major, Minor, Bld, Rbld) <
   PackVersionComponents(14, 14, 26429, 3));
```

---

Related question: [Compare version strings in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37825650/850848)

---

For the Windows version test, you can combine that with [`GetWindowsVersionEx`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversionex):

```pascal
GetWindowsVersionEx(WinVer);
WinVerPacked := PackVersionComponents(WinVer.Major, WinVer.Minor, WinVer.Build, 0);
if (ComparePackedVersion(WinVerPacked, PackVersionComponents(6, 1, 7601, 0)) < 0) or
   ((ComparePackedVersion(WinVerPacked, PackVersionComponents(6, 2, 0, 0)) >= 0) and
    (ComparePackedVersion(WinVerPacked, PackVersionComponents(6, 3, 0, 0)) < 0)) then
begin
  MsgBox(SetupMessage(msgWindowsVersionNotSupported), mbError, MB_OK);
  Result := False;
end;
```

And similarly as above, this should work too:

```pascal
if (WinVerPacked < PackVersionComponents(6, 1, 7601, 0)) or
   ((WinVerPacked >= PackVersionComponents(6, 2, 0, 0)) and
    (WinVerPacked < PackVersionComponents(6, 3, 0, 0))) then
```

---

There's nothing to be improved on your first scenario.