# Verify file version against set of known MD5 checksums in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

The following code works:

```pascal
[Code]
var
  ComMD5: Integer;
  FileExit: Boolean;

function InitializeSetup: boolean;
begin
  FileExit := FileExists(ExpandConstant('C:\Program Files (x86)\A\A.exe'));

  if FileExit = false then begin
    MsgBox('File does not exist！', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end else begin
    ComMD5 := CompareStr(GetMD5OfFile(ExpandConstant('C:\Program Files (x86)\A\A.exe')), 'c2d33f81e31eb54adf9323c27a9af536');
    if ComMD5 = 0 then begin
    MsgBox('The file version is incorrect, please install the correct version！', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
    end else
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

I want to perform MD5 verification on multiple versions, what should I do?

Condition: `A.exe` has been installed (there are 5 versions of `A.exe` successively, MD5 are `aMD5`/`bMD5`/`cMD5`/`dMD5`/`eMD5` respectively).

Use the installation package made by Inno Setup to compare the MD5 of `A.exe` at runtime.

If equal to `aMD5` or `bMD5`, the installer should continue.

If it is equal to `cMD5` or `dMD5` or `eMD5`, it should display

> The file version is incorrect, please install the correct version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been solved based on:

- [Can we use the new "Version" functions in Inno Setup 6.1 to make the script simpler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64872170/2287576)

```pascal
[Code]
function InitializeSetup: boolean;
var
  Path: string;
  MD5: string;
begin
  Path := ExpandConstant('{commonpf32}\A\A.exe');
  Result := FileExists(Path);

  if not Result then begin
    MsgBox('File does not exist!', mbError, MB_OK);
  end else begin
    MD5 := GetMD5OfFile(Path);
    if (MD5 = 'ab6fb7694839b404b53f0505f4d89f0e') or
       (MD5 = '152f7a2d99d3569202726864f4afbb45') then
    begin
      MsgBox('The file version is incorrect, please install the correct version!',
        mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end else
    if (MD5 = '34f871d51120216bed8deefa7147b857') or
       (MD5 = '5cd3e16c3a8374c448346277f11243c8') or
       (MD5 = '8fd90b3061795c553978d020c29d1f0b') then
    begin
      Log('The file version is correct');
    end
      else
    begin
      MsgBox('Unknown file version, please install a supported version!',
        mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```