# Inno Setup how to check if MSVCR100.dll exists on the system

Tags: visual-c++, inno-setup, pascal, redistributable, msvcr100.dll

I have an Inno Setup-based installer that also includes a [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) installer inside it. Installing WAMP on some systems requires the [installation for Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14557383/6243778) and I have those executables for those redistributables in my installer as well. Although, I want to check first if the system already has the MSVCR100.dll installed already so I would not need to launch those installers anymore. Any way on how to locate the MSVCR100.dll on the system using Inno-Setup?

I have tried searching the "MSVCR100.dll" in C:\ but there are a lot of results including some located in C:\Windows\SysWow64 and C:\Windows\System32

Note: We will only use 64-bit installation of wAMP, so we only need to find a way to locate the 64-bit redistributables. We can disregard the 32-bit for now.

Comment: *"there are a lot of results including some located in C:\Windows\SysWow64 and C:\Windows\System32"* - What what you need to now first, if the WAMP needs 32-bit or 64-bit redistributables.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it is 64-bit redistributables. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of detecting this .dll file simply run the redistributables setup file again:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2010/10/20/mailbag-how-to-perform-a-silent-install-of-the-visual-c-2010-redistributable-packages/

Running this setup twice will not harm the machine - if the redistributables are already installed nothing bad happens.

Comment: how can I incorporate this into Inno-Setup?

Comment: E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574035/how-to-install-microsoft-vc-redistributables-silently-in-inno-setup?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's a copy of the `MSVCR100.dll` in the `C:\Windows\System32`.

As the Inno Setup is a 32-bit application, you will actually need to check the `C:\Windows\sysnative`. For 32-bit applications, the `C:\Windows\System32` is redirected to the `C:\Windows\SysWow64`