# Inno Setup how to check dll file exist if not copy dll fie to system32 directory

Tags: inno-setup

I need check msvcr120.dll is exist. if not exist add msvcr120.dll to system32 directory. How can I do this with Inno Setup?

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't install that file directly by itself.  Since it is part of the Visual C++ 2013 Redistributables, you should run the redistributable installer (available at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) from your installer.

Comment: And that's covered in [How to install Microsoft VC++ redistributables silently in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24574035/850848)

Comment: But if I'm copy manualy msvcr120.dll to system32 directory problem fixed. Why I must install Visual C++ 2013 Redistributables?

Comment: Copying one file manually is not the Microsoft recommended way of dealing with system files.  What happens if you copy an older file than already exists? Or a newer file that has a different dependency.  The redistributables are provided for a reason.

Comment: You are right..

Comment: An example, that shows what might go wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66590707/850848