# Best way to distribute an application that requires Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, inno-setup

I have a commercial c++ application that calls Python files and uses Pytorch.

I will be shipping this application with an exe installer (created with Inno Setup) that also installs other dependencies, eg CUDA, by running an included exe installer.

My question is, how should I include a Pytorch installation with this application?

Locally I would use pip install, is that the best approach? Or can I somehow package a Pytorch installer with the application installer?

Comment: *"Or can I somehow package a Pytorch installer with the application installer?"* – Seems like sensible thing to do. You cannot expect your users to have `pip`.

Comment: Thanks! that confirms my thoughts. How though, does one package a pytorch installer?

Comment: You need something like this: [How to install Microsoft VC++ redistributables silently in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24574035/850848) – There are many other similar questions here.

Comment: Pytorch does not have an exe installer, is  the trouble. It appears to recommend using pip or conda.

Comment: So is seems that Pytorch actually does not need any installation. So why don't you just grap its binary(ies) and pack it (them) into your installer?

Comment: Ah i see! So i can just copy the whole package with the installer. Do i then need to create an environemnet variable so that python filers can find the pytorch location?

Comment: Well, that something I cannot answer  as I do not know PyTorch. But yes, it sounds good.